# Change dictionary's all values to 1

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

I want to change a dictionary's all values to 1 (float), I did research online but it seems people rarely have this random need.

The dictionary has thousands of entries, below is part of it

```
{
 '2015': [2.8216107792591907],
 '2016': [2.3686578052627687],
 '2017': [2.03069274701226]
}
```

Can someone give me some ideas ?  Thank you!

Comment: `{k: 1.0 for k in d.keys()}`

Comment: @Maroun why post this as a comment and not as an answer?

Comment: Do you want the values to be `1.0` or `[1.0]`?

Comment: please specify if you want the float to be placed instead of lists in your example, or inside them, instead of values

Comment: Please check my answer for a simple and efficient solution without any loops.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
myDict = {key : 1.0 for key in myDict}
```

Comment: You're not using `value`. Better using `d.keys()` and iterate only on it.

Comment: Using just `myDict` is enough for iteration over dict's keys.

Answer (score 2):

```
for element in my_dict:
    my_dict[element] = 1.0
```

Comment: Only answer to update (mutate) the existing `dict` object + readable and clean.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
d = {x: 1.0 for x in d}
```

That creates a new dictionary d that maps every key in d (the old one) to 1.

Answer (score 1):

I believe using `iterkeys()` is much efficient.

```
for k in d.iterkeys():
    d[k] = [1.0]
```

You can also do the same without any loops and in a single line using `fromkeys()`:

```
d = d.fromkeys(d, [1.0])
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: kudos for enlightening me about the fromkeys() method